# NSMutableArray insertObject: atIndex

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a problem with a NSMutableArray. I want to create a loop that fill an mutableArray initially empty but Xcode generates two error: "Assigning to "NSMutableArray" from incompatible type 'void'", "void value not ignored as it ought to be".
This is the code:

```
NSMutableArray * arrayToFill =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
int i=0;
while (i<4){
    NSDictionary * dictionary =[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"value1", @"key1",@"value2",@"key2", nil];
    arrayToFill =[arrayToFill insertObject:dictionary atIndex:i];
    i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line:

```
arrayToFill =[arrayToFill insertObject:dictionary atIndex:i];
```

to

```
[arrayToFill insertObject:dictionary atIndex:i];
```

You don't need to assign it again, just call the insert method

Answer (score 1):

simply remove the `arrayToFill =`

```
 NSMutableArray * arrayToFill = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        NSDictionary * dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"value1",  @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];
        [arrayToFill insertObject: dictionary atIndex: i ];
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change 5th line to this:

```
[arrayToFill insertObject:dictionary atIndex:i];
```

You don't have to reassign the arrayToFill